# How to run the model program remotely

Tags: anylogic

I have converted the model to a standalone program and I can access it through the web, for example my access is "the simulation webservice url: http://localhost:25042". I enter "http://localhost:25042" into my browser locally and it works fine, but when I access this "25042" over the LAN (by replacing localhost with IP address), I get the web page, but it says "if you wish to run the model frontend on a remote device, please contact the Anylogic support".

I would like to know:
Do you have similar experience?
How can I contact Anylogic to solve this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjqw8.jpg)

I have converted the model to a standalone program and I can access it through the web, for example my access is "the simulation webservice url: http://localhost:25042". I enter "http://localhost:25042" into my browser locally and it works fine, but when I access this "25042" over the LAN (by replacing localhost with IP address), I get the web page, but it says "if you wish to run the model frontend on a remote device, please contact the Anylogic support".

Comment: i think to do this you need the anylogic private cloud... so do as it says and contact anylogic